# rails - select all checkboxes inside a div before submitting form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a new batch form where user can select books from a div using the checkbox and click on a button to put them in another div which represents the selected books.

It works a bit like a listbox where user can move items between the different boxes except that here am using checkbox and div.

I have done the moving of books from one div to another using jquery.

See code below:

```
<% form_for @batch do |f| %>
<label style="width: 150px">Batch Name:</label><%= f.text_field :BAT_BATCH_NAME %>  



<div id="all_books">

<% @books.each do |book| %>
<div id="book<%= book.BK_OID %>" bookid="<%= book.BK_OID %>" class="innertxt">

<ul>
<li>Book ID: <%= book.BK_OID %></li>
<li>Name: <%= book.BK_NAME %></li>
<li>
<input type="checkbox" name="batch[book_ids][]" id="select<%= book.BK_OID %>"  value=<%= book.BK_OID %> class="selectit" />

</li>
</ul>

</div>
<% end %>


<div style="width:100px; text-align:center; margin-left:20px; padding-top: 100px; width:75px; float:left;">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="move_right">Right &raquo;</a><br /><br />
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="move_left">&laquo; Left</a>
</div>


<div id="selected_books"> </div>
<br/><br/>

<%= f.submit 'Update Batch Details' %>


<% end %>
```

Currently, only the selected books are saved, whether they are found in the 'all_books' div or 'selected_books' div.

However, I want all entries in the 'selected_books' div to be submitted when saving the batch, whether their checkboxes have been checked or not. and ignore all selected entries in the 'all_books' div.

In short, when saving the batch, i want to save only those books found in the 'selected_books' div and ignore the rest whether their checkboxes have been checked or not.

I hope i was clear enough.

I would be really grateful if someone could point me the right direction on how to do that.

Many many thanks for any suggestion provided.

Comment: do i need to write a jquery function to deselect all checkboxes in the 'all_books' div and select all checkboxes in the 'selected_books' div before saving the form??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#formid").submit(function(){ $("#selected_books").find("input:checkbox").attr({checked: "checked"}); });
```

That should do the trick.